# AR on iphone using ZXing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, augmented-reality, zxing

Has anyone attempted to use ZXing with an iphone AR toolkit like ARToolKit? Trying to use a QR code as a marker to display my models on an iphone.

Is the ZXing project sufficient to get the dimensions of the QR code to feed to the ARToolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the easiest way is to reverse those steps, so you use AR toolkit to determine the image-segment to feed to ZXing (or similar). There's a paper called "Applying QR Code in Augmented Reality Application" that describes an approach like this.

The position detectors in QR codes are registered patterns with ARToolkit, so it will find those by itself. The trick is to determine the bounding box of the QR code from the three position detectors, then apply the perspective projection necessary to give a perpendicular view of the code (given by AR toolkit) so the unwarped QR image can be fed to the QR library (they normally can't deal with much distortion).